# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

this is my query

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[CountUses](@couponid INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
   BEGIN
   RETURN
    (
    SELECT  c.Id,
     c.Name,
     c.CreateDate,
     Count(cu.id) NofUses
  FROM   Coupon as  c
     JOIN CouponUse as cu
       ON c.id = cu.couponid
 GROUP  BY c.Id,
     c.Name,
     c.CreateDate
     )
 END
```

its giving the error `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.` where is the problem ?
Aside from the main answer, I'd also appreciate any comments you may have about optimizing my query...

Comment: A scalar function can only return one value, not four.  Have a look at a [table-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: your function trying to return recordset and not int. what do you want to get as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your function to return more than one value, then you need to look at [Table-Valued Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

These types of functions return a table and not just one value.  Your current function is set up as a scalar function so it can only return one value.

If you want a scalar value - let's say just the `count` then your function will be similar to this:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[CountUses](@couponid INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
   BEGIN
   RETURN
    (
      SELECT Count(cu.id) NofUses  --- this can only return one column
      FROM   Coupon as  c
      JOIN CouponUse as cu
        ON c.id = cu.couponid
      WHERE cu.couponid = @couponid
     )
   END
```

If you intention is to return a table of data, then your function will be similar to this:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[CountUses](@couponid INT)
RETURNS @new_table table
(
  id int,
  name varchar(50),
  CreateDate datetime,
  NofUsers int
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @new_table
  SELECT c.Id,
       c.Name,
       c.CreateDate,
       Count(cu.id) NofUses
      FROM   Coupon as  c
      JOIN CouponUse as cu
        ON c.id = cu.couponid
      WHERE cu.couponid = @couponid
      GROUP  BY c.Id,  c.Name,  c.CreateDate

   RETURN
END
```

Comment: thanks, @bluefeet you saved me , One last thing how can i make `NofUses` index because when i am trying this statement `CREATE INDEX Noofusesindex
ON Coupon (NofUses)` its giving this error `Column 'NofUses' in table 'Coupon' cannot be used in an index or statistics or as a partition key because it is non-deterministic.`

Comment: @Smartboy Here is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214775(v=sql.80).aspx) about non-deterministic functions. If you have any questions about creating the index, I would post another question as I am not sure it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the issue:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[CountUses](@couponid INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT  c.Id,
            c.Name,
            c.CreateDate,
            Count(cu.id) NofUses
    FROM   Coupon as  c
    JOIN CouponUse as cu
         ON c.id = cu.couponid
    GROUP  BY c.Id,
              c.Name,
              c.CreateDate
)
```